# Avoid Certificate authentication in a swt browser

Tags: java, swt

I am using a swt browser to open a page that requires login. Normally it should display a username and password page but since I have certificates imported it picks up a certificate and automatically logs in.
Is there a way to prevent this ,so that imported certificates are ignored and always the username and password page is displayed?

Here is the code:

```
Browser browser = new Browser(browserShell, SWT.Resize);  
browserShell.setSize(580, 550);
browser.setSize(browserShell.getSize());
GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(browserShell); 
GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(browser); 
browser.setUrl("url");
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Look at Window -> Preferences -> General -> Security -> Secure Storage -> Contents in Eclipse and see if you see certs here. It is just caching them somewhere in eclipse. I would find the location and then delete them.

Comment: Nope . The certificates were not listed there. The only way i found to prevent their use is to delete them or change their purpose for use .But what i need is to do it through code if possible.

Comment: If you can locate where the certs are placed, then you can remove them with code...